# Why is pattern matching in an if statement frowned upon?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I just installed the [Credo](https://github.com/rrrene/credo) mix library in my Phoenix app and it's telling me that the `web/views/error_helpers.ex` file has a refactoring opportunity in the error tag method:

```rb
def error_tag(form, field) do
  if error = form.errors[field] do
    content_tag :span, translate_error(error), class: "help-block"
  end
end
```

The message Credo gives is:

> There should be no matches in `if` conditions.

In other words `if error = form.errors[field] do` has a pattern match in it.  But, beyond that message, the Credo library doesn't elaborate.

Why is this bad?

Comment: I think the justification is to prevent accidental `=` when people meant `==`. I disagree with credo on this and many other points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like the other posters have said it is less idiomatic and can cause some trouble analyzing (or common erros like typing `=` instead of `==`). My main argument for this are the following cases:

```
if get_status = :ok do 
  # Some code
else
  # Some other code
```

this is very limiting and not very expressive, with `cond do` you may do the following:

```
cond get_status do
  :ok -> # Some code
  :not_ok -> # Some other code
  _ -> # More code
end
```

If conditions are pretty much binary, you either get A or get something else. This is good if the result is a boolean from a local function call or similar, but if you are working on a distributed system, getting info from another machine or similar, `cond do` is much more powerful, concise and helps you reason and set up code for unexpected behaviour (the underscore in the above code, if `get_status` is a function that gets the status of a certain service that we expect something like :ok for the service being ready and :not_ok if the service is not ready, then what about if the service's machine is down? or maybe our network cable disconnected?).

Of course this can be achieved with multiple `if` statements, but that leads to poor code that is not very readable or maintainable.

Answer (score 1):

It's not so much bad, but very often `if` expressions are less idiomatic. Alternatives like `case` and `cond` are much more powerful and can be much more explicit about what happens and can cause more predictable behavior. There might be a few cases (like this one) where this code is fine, and I don't know how easily it would be to analyze this case compared to others. This expression, for instance, returns nil when there's no error...which isn't altogether as explicit as handling 2 cases and providing an empty string.